# Admin: Order View not showing product's ordered attribute

Tags: admin, magento-1, sales

I want to display more attribute like **size|gender|color** in Magento Sales-->Order section Below is the code I used to get these details

**File Path-** `/app/design/adminhtml/default/mytheme/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml`

**Code-**

```
  <?php if ($_item = $this->getItem()):?>
    <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
    <div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->htmlEscape($this->getSku()))); ?></div>
<?php   
?>
    <?php if ($this->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($this->getOrderOptions() as $_option):
             //print_r($_option);
         ?>
            <dt><?php echo $_option['label'] ?></dt>
            <dd>
            <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php $_option = $this->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                <?php echo $_option['value']; ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?php echo $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid()?>"> ...</span><span id="<?php echo $_id = 'id' . uniqid()?>"><?php //echo $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').hide();
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php echo $_id ?>').show();});
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php echo $_dots?>').hide();});
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php echo $_id ?>').hide();});
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php echo $_dots ?>').show();});
                    </script>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php //echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here I can get SKU but `$this->getOrderOptions()` is returns empty array so code below `if($this->getOrderOptions()):)`  not works. Please help me on this. I have attached image below for more information[image]